Learning drum single strokes - may my forearms actually be different?
I have been learning drums for about 5 days or so. I've realized that my left forearm or arm's structure might actually be different from my right forearm, as I am learning to play as symmetrically as possible.
I play single strokes with a flat down palm (and then gripping the drumstick), on the right side I achieve that with ease, but on the left side I think it wants to hold the drumstick differently.
Anybody got similar things going on?

This is on the assumption OP is right-handed?

There are different ways in which to hold the sticks.
If you're trying to play matched grip, with both hands facing the same way, and your arms don't want to do that, then try traditional grip, which seems to be more natural for you. Either and positions in between are all acceptable!

I agree with Tim.
Form follows function.
If one technique works for the left hand, and another technique is intuitively more comfortable for the right hand, then that's the direction you want to take with your drumming.

Indeed, peoples' bodies (and brains) are not reliably symmetrical... so it is reasonable to not necessarily have the left and right parts behave identically. Not only for drums, but also keyboard, especially more classical piano (familiar to me). The roles in the latter are not symmetrical, besides! :)

What if they want to play a percussion instrument that isn't snare or drum kit?  Matched grip is typically used for pretty much every thing else that is hit with sticks or mallets.

@Edward - there are millions of 'what ifs' in life. This question doesn't address any except playing a drum kit. But if? Let's cross that bridge when we get to it. You're right that drums/cymbals are probably a special case.

Why do you think a different grip would help with this very common problem?

@ToddWilcox - I don't. OP needs to do what suits best.

Ok. I’m not able to find the aspects of this answer that are about anything other than grip. I disagree that traditional grip is worth trying outside of playing a field snare that is carried to the side while marching - the situation that traditional grip was developed for. If you’re not suggesting a different grip, what are you suggesting?

@ToddWilcox - this will not turn into a slanging match! OP seems concerned that matching doesn't suit, hence the question. Other alternatives are available... If all else fails, we agree that 'get a teacher' is the real answer.

I guess I’ll just stop commenting to explain my downvotes then.

@ToddWilcox - didn't know it was yours!

I can just about understand one of the dvs, but the others?

I downvoted.  Traditional grip has many downsides that matched does not have, and it is not a good solution IMO to the problem of not immediately getting the hang of matched grip.  Also, re: what ifs, it wasn't clear to me that OP is playing a drum kit, much less planning to exclusively play drum kit and nothing else, so I still think that not learning matched grip is unnecessarily limiting.

As almost all of us have handedness, as in a preference to use one hand more than the other for tasks that require dexterity, it’s almost universal that when we start learning drums, we can’t immediately play symmetrically with the same sound, dynamic, and timing with both hands.
There are popular strategies for dealing with asymmetrical hand tendencies in drumming. The most obvious is to spend more practice time working with the hand that is weaker or less coordinated. Just practice basic strokes with your off hand. Compare how your dominant hand plays each type of stroke and practice with the off hand to mirror the technique.
Another thing to pay attention to is when playing with both hands, make sure the height of the sticks before the stroke is the same. When practicing rolls and patterns, this means making sure the rebounds come up to the same height on both hands. This helps ensure timing and dynamics are more symmetrical between hands.
As always in music practice, and especially with percussion, metronome practice is key. In addition to playing with a metronome, count and subdivide along with the metronome while playing. This is key to improve even timing between hands.
Even playing between hands is a constant challenge for the entire life of most percussion players. Of course once you’ve gained competence it is easier to improve and maintain, but we can never ignore the asymmetry of our hands or we risk losing our ability to play evenly.

Seems that OP is more concerned about each hand having a different position, rather than trying to play matched grip. If so, so be it. Played with many drummers who play as if they are wearing a side drum, therefore don't use matched grip, and if anything, their playing is superior.

@Tim I’ve interpreted this question differently from the other answerers, including you. Perhaps because my experience was also that something felt structurally wrong with my left hand when I started drumming, but I’ve learned that for me it’s just different muscle development due to handedness.

After thinking about it for a couple days, this question starts to sound more and more to me like the old "Are my fingers too big for guitar?" "Is something wrong with my fretting hand pinky?" "Do I need a short scale bass if I'm x foot y?"  Usually the answer is no.  It is likely that OP just needs to put in the time to learn the coordination.  I do still stand by my recommendation of American grip, though.

@Edward I am eager to learning this, I have practiced for about a week every day for 4 hours ... okay... hmm... maybe thats not very much? just stopped myself from writing more after "4 hours"

There are 3 different matched grips that are commonly taught- "French" (palms face each other), "German" (palms face the floor), and "American" (halfway in between).
You might not be able to comfortably do German grip with your left hand, but you can probably do a symmetrical American grip.
Also, seeing that you've only been learning for 5 days, I wouldn't discount the possibility of learning German grip.  Perhaps it is just a matter of doing some light stretching or mobility exercises, or just learning the coordination required- very few untrained people will naturally hold drumsticks "correctly" without being taught how.  You probably don't need to, though- you can play everything with American grip.
There is value in symmetry.  Asymmetrical grips are naturally harder to get an even hand-to-hand sound with.  I have one shoulder slightly higher than the other, but I do try to correct it and keep my hands symmetrical.  Of course, there is a popular asymmetrical grip- traditional grip, which is mainly used because of, well, tradition.  It originally invented because matched grip was terrible for a drum carried on a sling.  And now, lots of people like how it looks.  But an asymmetrical matched grip would just look strange to any trained percussionist, while also having the practical difficulties that arise from asymmetry.
Also, a warning- if you want to use traditional grip to avoid some left hand mobility issue- many people don't have the mobility to do play traditional grip that easily either!  Legato strokes at a vertical stick height are quite a stretch!

Why do you think a different grip would help with this very common problem?

OP describes that they have some trouble holding the stick in German grip with their left hand.  It seems clear to me how American grip would help- it's a more neutral hand position, and not the one they are currently having problems with.

That’s fair. I didn’t interpret their question as being about trouble holding the stick but it’s not 100% clear either way

@ToddWilcox  I have trouble holding the stick "german", in terms of the left hand not being symmetrical...

@watchme That’s not very clear to me. What kind of trouble do you have? Are your left and right hands clearly different shapes or sizes, or do they just feel different when you play drums?

@ToddWilcox i feel like they may have a slightly different structure - my arms... when I look at my hands positions I often see they arent symmetrically - for instance when practicing single strokes or after doing them - but we have the same question unfortunately - they sometimes feel the same and it feels good playing with them, but I just realize that its actually not symmetrically - also sometimes by looking at the playing result. They have a different path and it doesnt look "beautiful" - thats how I judge if I play symmetrically :-) I hope I am not too confusing, I have veryhighstandards

@ToddWilcox I sometimes guess that I may have had an injury at one of my arms or joints or something... or too little practice. I just wanted to ask whats your all opinions

@watchme Opinions are off topic here. If your arms aren’t clearly different and if you don’t absolutely remember a serious injury then you’re almost certainly in the same boat as the rest of us. We all have to work hard on making our playing even between hands because no one’s hands are 100% symmetrical.

@ToddWilcox yup, I wanted to know how common different arm-structures are for instance ... if thats "a thing" or if I just suck haha thanks Todd

I have one song that requires a really weird position on the floor tom on the intro, so when I play that intro I sit turned to have an easier time hitting the floor tom with the left stick (my floor tom is on the right, which is normal for most songs and a right handed player). As Sparquelito said, form follows function, so if a specific function requires you to have a weird form, thats fine
